# If a payment contains 1-1 mapping with transfer and each transfer contains 1-many mapping with attempts, how should I model my data vault

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse, datamodel, data-vault

Trying to model a process on process in DV 2.0.

If a payment contains 1-1 mapping with transfer and each transfer contains 1-many mapping with attempts, how should I model my data vault

Unable to understand how to model these scenarios of one process initiating another processes in Data Vault 2.0

[image: Current DV Model]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, link are designed to be a many-to-many relationship only. this cover all relation that could exists in past, present and future (if business logics change, you won't have to redesign your DV).

Second, do not create a link-to-link relationship, that is bad design. A link must represent relationship between business entities, not between business entities and relationship.

To answer your question, take a look at the transactional link (aka non-historized link), it should suit your need. without having your model, here's what the transaction link could look like :

```
__hashKeyLink            : hashkey for the link
__hashKeyHubPayement     : hashkey for the payment
__hashKeyHubTransfert    : hashkey for the transfert
__attempt                : int,  assuming attempt is a sequence number unique per transfert
__loadDate, source ...   : others system fields
```

Comment: does data vault link design for one-to-many relationship as well?